# Issue with .netcore 2.1 logging to Azure Blobs

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have a .netcore 2.1 api. I am trying to do some logging in Azure Blobs.

I have been using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices(version 2.2.0) in .netcore 2.2 api's with no issue and it logs information to the Azure blobs beautifully.

But when I try the same code with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices (version 2.1.1) in .netcore 2.1 it fails to log the information (even though I get the desired out from the API endpoint).

Code that I have tried,in program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

        var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogInformation("Main() method.");

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            })
            .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection
                .Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
                    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
                    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
                }).Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.BlobName = "Log.txt";
                }))
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

And in azure I have added the settings as in the image below.

[image]

Now to test it I had added some logging in the starup.cs and program.cs and controller.cs.

Logs from Startup.cs is being printed into the output blobs, but the other cs files are unable to log the information into the blob.

Anybody has any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To configure provider settings, use [AzureFileLoggerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.azureappservices.azurefileloggeroptions) and [AzureBlobLoggerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.azureappservices.azureblobloggeroptions), as shown in the following example:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics())
        .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection
                .Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
                    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
                    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
                }).Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.BlobName = "log.txt";
                }))
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

or Alternatively like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureLogging"));
    }
```

Appsettings.json

```
"AzureLogging": {
     "FileName" : "azure-diagnostics-",
     "FileSizeLimit": 50024,
     "RetainedFileCountLimit": 5
}
```

When you deploy to an App Service app, the application honors the settings in the App Service logs section of the App Service page of the Azure portal. When the following settings are updated, the changes take effect immediately without requiring a restart or redeployment of the app.

- Application Logging (Filesystem)
- Application Logging (Blob)

[image]

Please ensure to have setting like above.Hope it helps.

Comment: How will it write to the blob, when Application logging (blob) is off in the above settings. And I think your Program.cs is same as mine(if you have a look at my code example). I have just added the DI for extra logging.